# How does, Defining and Instantiating variables in class scope, interpretted internally

Tags: c#, compiler-construction, instantiation

Class1 declares a variable and instantiates it. defining and instantiating statement is allowed to be class scope.

```
class class1
{
public bool variable = false;
}
```

With the same logic why cannot Class2 instantiate the variable. why instantiating statement is not allowed to be in class scope like this.

```
class class2 : class1
{
variable = false;
}
```

**I am interested, if there is any logical explanation behind this.** May be the Compiler interprets such defining in some special way.

Comment: My guess is variable gets initialized before class1 is -constructed-. so class2 can not initialize the variable a second time.

Answer (score 1):

Other than inline initialization, statements are not allowed in the class body without being contained in something like a constructor, method, or property.

If you want to initialize the variable to something else, stick it in the constructor (this is what the constructor is for):

```
public class Class2 : Class1
{
    public Class2()
    {
        variable = false;
    }
}
```

Another similar question:

[Statements only in methods, but what about declarations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3866055/statements-only-in-methods-but-what-about-declarations)

In summary, declaration is only allowed at class scope. Inline initialization is equivalent to initializing the member variables in the constructor - my guess is this was added as syntactic sugar, as inline initialization is stock-and-trade for lots of languages.

Also a quick note on the naming, classes are usually Title Cased.

Comment: :) Thanks adam. But i wanted to understand, why is this so.. is there any explanation?

Comment: The logical explanation is that it was a design choice not to support this behaviour - it can be achieved by using a constructor. If you want to understand the reason for the design choice, you'd need to speak to someone on the Microsoft team responsible for it.

Answer (score 0):

Never saw a problem with your second case, except the fact that in **second** case you didn't define a TYPE of the variable.

**EDIT**

I think I missuderstood your question:

The member `variable` is a part of the base class definiton. You can not access a *public*  member of a class out of any method. That is it.